# Reset Auto Increment by day in visual studio - SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, increment, localdb

I´m looking for an solution to reset the auto increment id by day change.

Let's say you have a order and you want to store 2 identification numbers...
the daylie order number and the order itself.

E.g. ORDER#123123 ORDERDAY#3 Article#Something, etc.

The order number will be auto increment and primary while the day id will be just a counter to see how many orders the company got in a day.

The day counter has to reset itself by new day.

I´m currently working on a windows forms project with a local SQL Server database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Michael, as you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. Please go through the answers and vote them up if they are helpful. If one of them helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer, Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a job that resets the day id to 1 each day:

[MSDN SQL Server - Schedule a job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you store the date and a running ID (an `IDENTITY column`) you can achieve this easily with

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YourDateColumn ORDER BY YourIDColumn) AS DayId 
FROM Your Table
```

ATTENTION: If you store the Time together with the Date you'd have to make sure, that the `PARTITION BY`is done with the pure date value!

Just never delete a row physically, if you need deletions, mark them as deleted with sort of a status column.

You should use an instead of trigger for delete operations to ensure data integrity...